# How to fill gap between brickwork and new door lining

Tags: brick, plaster, gap

I have just had someone install a new door lining, it's not gone off without a hitch unfortunately.

I have been advised to fill the large gap with bonding but it's 190mm deep and my (not small) palm fits in fully.

I am looking for good ideas on how to fill this correctly, so that when the plasterer comes to tidy up around it, the surface is suitable and ready to be plastered.

Thank you

[image: text]

Comment: Does plaster work need to be done? Typically the trim around the door covers the gap, unless it is extra wide. Is it extra wide? Maybe wider trim would be an option?

Comment: Yes, the trim even at 57mm doesn't cover the bulk of the middle gap.

Comment: Wider trim may be a less expensive option then plasterers. 57mm is only  just over 2 inches, How wide is the gap to be covered?

Comment: I've a plasterer coming soon to plaster the room the other side of the door. Wider trim would create more work with altering laminate and skirting.